numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility
I am using Numpy version 2.x.  I get this error:
from catboost import CatBoostClassifier

 File "_catboost.pyx", line 1, in init _catboost
ValueError: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96 from C header, got 88 from PyObject

I downloaded version 1.16+ of numpy and minus catboost but no change.

This question is similar to: ValueError: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96 from C header, got 88 from PyObject. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It appears that catboost is not compatible with NumPy 2.0 at the time of this question (see e.g. https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/2671).
To fix the issue, you should install NumPy 1.26 or older. You report trying NumPy 1.16; this version may be too old for some of the other catboost requrirements, which could lead to a similar error. I'd suggest trying a more recent NumPy 1.X version, such as 1.26.

To solve this problem, you first need to install a python version under 3.12, I installed 3.9. Creating a venv with virtualenv and activating python 3.9 in it, then installing numpy ==1.22.4 and installing it again with pip install catboost solves the problem.

I don't think the interpreter version is relevant. That being said, I don't see any valuable information in this answer that isn't already given by the other answer.

You may not think so, but I encountered the same problem and when I did it, this was the method I reached the solution, would it hurt to try?
